# How to use a specific stop-character for shlex.split?

Tags: python, shlex

How to tell to `shlex` that if the character `;` is found, then, don't split anything anymore?

Example:

```
shlex.split("""hello "column number 2" foo ; bar baz""")
```

should give

```
["hello", "column number 2", "foo", "; bar baz"]
```

instead of `["hello", "column number 2", "foo", ";", "bar", "baz"]`.

---

More generally, is there a way to define "comment" separators with `shlex`? i.e.

```
shlex.split("""hello "column number 2" foo ;this is a comment; "last one" bye """)
```

should give

```
["hello", "column number 2", "foo", ";this is a comment;", "last one", "bye"]
```

Comment: Shlex lets you configure the comment character(s). But it doesn't include comments in the return value. And it really stops when it sees a comment character; there's no such thing as "two comments". If that's all ok, then it's straightforward.

Comment: Oh yes it would be ok @rici, how do you do this?

Comment: `shlex` isn't supposed to be configurable: it parses lines the same way a POSIX-compliant shell would.

Comment: @chepner: then why does it have all those [configuration options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex-objects)? (In part, of course, because shells differ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shlex` parser provides an option for specifying the comment character(s), but it's not available from the simplified `shlex.split` interface. Example:

```
import shlex

a = 'hello "bla bla" ; this is a comment'

lex = shlex.shlex(a, posix=True)
lex.commenters = ';'
print(list(lex))  # ['hello', 'bla bla']
```

Here is a slightly expanded `split` function, mostly copied from the Python standard library, with a slight modification to the `comments` parameter, allowing the specification of comment characters:

```py
import shlex
def shlex_split(s, comments='', posix=True):
    """Split the string *s* using shell-like syntax."""
    if s is None:
        import warnings
        warnings.warn("Passing None for 's' to shlex.split() is deprecated.",
                      DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
    lex = shlex.shlex(s, posix=posix)
    lex.whitespace_split = True
    if isinstance(comments, str):
        lex.commenters = comments
    elif not comments:
        lex.commenters = ''
    return list(lex)
```

You might want to change the default value of `comments` in the above code; as written, it has the same default as `shlex.split`, which is not to recognise comments at all. (The parser objects created by `shlex.shlex` default to `#` as the comment character, which is what you get if you specify `comments=True`. I preserved this behaviour for compatibility.)

Note that comments are ignored; they do not appear in the result vector at all. When the parser hits a comment character, it just stops parsing. (So there can never be two comments.) The `comments` string is a list of possible comments characters, not a comment sequence. So if you want to recognise both `#` and `;`  as comment characters, specify `comments='#:'`.

Here's a sample run:

```
>>> # Default behaviour is the same as shlex.split
>>> shlex_split("""hello "column number 2" foo ; bar baz""") 
['hello', 'column number 2', 'foo', ';', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> # Supply a comments parameter to specify a comment character 
>>> shlex_split("""hello "column number 2" foo ; bar baz""", comments=';') 
['hello', 'column number 2', 'foo']
>>> shlex_split("""hello "column number 2" foo ;this is a comment; "last one" bye """, comments=';')
['hello', 'column number 2', 'foo']
>>> # The ; is recognised as a comment even if it is not preceded by whitespace.
>>> shlex_split("""hello "column number 2" foo;this is a comment; "last one" bye """, comments=';')
['hello', 'column number 2', 'foo']
```

Comment: Thanks @rici! In the first example, you wrote "it is available", I think you wanted to say "it is *not* available in the simplified split interface", I edited to fix, as well as a typo, I hope it's ok for you. I also added a very minimal example.